# Find an element $g\in S_6$ such that $g(123)(456)g^{-1}=(531)(264)$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Calculate the number of different conjugacy classes in $S_6$ and write down a representative permutation for each class. Find an element $g\in S_6$ such that $g(123)(456)g^{-1}=(531)(264)$.

I calculated the number of conjugacy classes in $S_6$, which is 11, and wrote down the permutation for each class, but I dont know how to find the $g$ such that $g(123)(456)g^{-1}=(531)(264)$. So far I tried to do some puzzling to find $g$, but I didn't succeed. I feel like there's a better way to find $g$ than continue to puzzle.

I'd appreciate some tips on how to find $g$!

---

By luck I found the answer,$g=(25)$, but I'd still like to know the general idea on how to solve this

Comment: Brute forcing yields 18 solutions. They confirm @Stefan4024's hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$g(123)(456)g^{-1} = (g(1),g(2),g(3))(g(4),g(5),g(6))$$

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with the $g(1), g(2)$ etc, could you explain it? Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas $g(1)$ is the element to which $1$ is sent by $g$.